# Solution without HAVING clause

Tags: sql, postgresql

For the exercise

https://pgexercises.com/questions/aggregates/fachours1a.html

with the schema diagrams:

[image]

I'm trying to: "Produce a list of facilities with more than 1000 slots booked. Produce an output table consisting of facility id and slots, sorted by facility id."

The solution using the `having` clause is quite simple

```
select facid, sum(slots) as "Total Slots"
    from cd.bookings
    group by facid
    having sum(slots) > 1000
order by facid
```

For my own practice, I'm trying to produce a solution that does **not** use `having`, but I've been stuck for some time now. How do I do that please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a subquery:

```
select f.*
from (select facid, sum(slots) as TotalSlots
      from cd.bookings
      group by facid
     ) f
where TotalSlots > 1000
order by facid;
```

I'm not sure *why* you would want to do this, but you can.

Comment: It's just for practicing. Cool trick, at least for a beginner like me. Thanks! Is "having" standard with different SQL dialects?

Comment: @yurnero . . . `having` is totally standard.  The only quirk is that some databases allow the use of column aliases in the `having` clause and some do not -- you need to repeat the aggregation expression.